# Recieving an "expected an integer constant" error in Code Composer Studio (C)

Tags: c

I've been working on this code for homework for one of my classes and I really can't figure out how to get rid of this error. I'm really lost on why my bitwise shift is not being recognized as an integer constant. Any help is appreciated

```
#include <msp430g2553.h>

#define red_LED   BIT0
#define BTN       BIT3

    int long t;                         //min & max 0 & 4294967295
    int pressCnt = 3;                   //pressCnt=1 so that you can divide

void main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;           // turn off watch-dog timer
    P1DIR |= red_LED;                   // LED pins to outputs, BTN is
                                        // still an input by default.
    P1OUT = 0;                          // turn off both LEDs
    P1OUT = 0x08;                       // P1.3 set
    P1REN |= 0x08;                      // P1.3 pullup
    t = 500000000;                      // initial time where it is 100        blinks a second

 while (t>=500000)                      //time where it is 1 blink per second
 {
    P1OUT  = 0x01;                      // LED on
    _delay_cycles((int) t>>pressCnt);
    P1OUT = 0x00;                       // LED off
    _delay_cycles((int) t>>pressCnt);
    if ((P1IN & BTN) == 0);
        pressCnt++;
 }
}
```

Comment: `(int) t>>pressCnt`  does not look like a constant.  Use a constant as the parameter to `_delay_cycles()`.

Comment: Also your while loop is infinite since `t` never changes.

Comment: So should I re write everything under the while loop? What I am attempting to do is have a LED blink 100 times a second and every time the button is pressed the blink rate is reduced to half its value until it blinks at a rate of 1 blink per second